# RFECV giving same test scores for every feature size

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I am trying to reduce the feature space of my training dataset down from the 16000 it currently is before engaging in Random Forest Classification.

Initially I removed all features in less that 5% of samples (leaving me with the 16000) and I am trying to further reduce this by RFECV. To do this am am using the following:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV

selector = LogisticRegression(penalty = 'l1', solver='liblinear')
cv = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 5)

rfecv = RFECV(estimator = selector,
              step = 2,
              cv = cv,
              scoring = 'accuracy',
              min_features_to_select = 1,
              n_jobs = 8)

rfecv.fit(train_16S, train_16S_labels)
```

However the `rfecv.cv_results_["mean_test_score"]` are all the same:
[image]

I have previously seen the problem reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67434259/exactly-same-values-for-accuracy-in-rfecv) and the solutions was to use no penalty but but from reading around using `penalty = 'l1'` and `solver='liblinear'`is common for this problem?